# Template of a a webpage with a header, footer, side blocks, and main block

Tags: css, html

I have made a template of a web page (the code's below). The problem I found is I cannot make the side sections to stick to left and right edges so that the middle would fill the remaining space. I tried to use floats left / right of the CSS but it did not work. I'd need the three blocks to stay separated regardless of they contain. I also tried to change display to inline-block. The code below shows how far I could go. The code is also available on [here on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZikO/4hxxhLs1/).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            section,article,header,footer,nav,aside,h1,h2,h3,h4,p,ul,li {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            html {
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #00d;
            }
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: #ddf;
            }
            nav {
                background-color: red;
            }
            footer {
                background-color: yellow;
                clear: both;
            }
            li {
                list-style-type: none;
                list-style-image: none;
            }
            #top {
                background-color: grey;
                padding: 10px 20px;
            }
            #container {
                width: 100%;
            }
            #left {
                vertical-align: top;
                background-color: cyan;
                width: 15%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            #main {
                width: auto;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            #right {
                vertical-align: top;
                background-color: magenta;
                width: 25%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="top">
            <h1>Top header</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <h2>Navigation bar</h2>
        </nav>
        <section id="container">
            <aside id="left">
                <ul>
                    <li>Left</li>
                    <li>Left</li>
                    <li>Left</li>
                    <li>Left</li>
                    <li>Left</li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
            <section id="main">
                <h2>Articles</h2>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h4>Article 1</h4>
                    </header>
                    <p>You can easily change the fo</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h4>Article 2</h4>
                    </header>
                    <p>Include items that are .</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h4>Article 3</h4>
                    </header>
                    <p>You can easily change th.</p>
                </article>
            </section>
            <aside id="right">
                <ul>
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>First</li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
        </section>
        <nav>
            <h2>Navigation bar</h2>
        </nav>
        <footer>
            <h4>The footer</h4>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

I managed to obtain the result by employing the table, tr, and td HTML tags but I am not really happy with that. I would like to understand what else I can do. I would be grateful if someone could help me with this how I could use proper just CSS selectors to obtain the same result. I attached another the code so present the final effect. Also this code is available  on [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZikO/bvk31n52/5/).

Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            section,article,header,footer,nav,aside,h1,h2,h3,h4,p,ul,li,table,td,th {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            html {
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0;
            }
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            nav {
                background-color: red;
            }
            footer {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            li {
                list-style-type: none;
                list-style-image: none;
            }
            table,th,td {
                border: 0;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                vertical-align: top;
            }
            table#maintable {
                width: 100%;
            }
            table#maintable td:nth-child(1) {
                width: 150px;
                background-color: #fcf;
            }
            table#maintable td:nth-child(2) {
                width: auto;
                background-color: #cfc;
            }
            table#maintable td:nth-child(3) {
                width: 250px;
                background-color: #dff;
            }
            #top {
                background-color: grey;
                padding: 10px 20px;
            }
            #artheader {
                background-color: #8f8;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="top">
            <h1>Top header</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <h2>Navigation bar</h2>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <table id="maintable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <aside>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Left</li>
                                <li>Left</li>
                                <li>Left</li>
                                <li>Left</li>
                                <li>Left</li>
                            </ul>
                        </aside>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <section>
                            <header id="artheader">
                                <h2>Articles</h2>
                            </header>
                            <article>
                                <header>
                                    <h4>Article 1</h4>
                                </header>
                                <p>You can easily change the fo</p>
                            </article>
                            <article>
                                <header>
                                    <h4>Article 2</h4>
                                </header>
                                <p>Include items that are .</p>
                            </article>
                            <article>
                                <header>
                                    <h4>Article 3</h4>
                                </header>
                                <p>You can easily change th.</p>
                            </article>
                        </section>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <aside>
                            <ul>
                                <li>First</li>
                                <li>First</li>
                                <li>First</li>
                                <li>First</li>
                                <li>First</li>
                            </ul>
                        </aside>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
        <nav>
            <h2>Navigation bar</h2>
        </nav>
        <footer>
            <h4>The footer</h4>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use flexbox http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Are you just looking for anothr way to get your template designed but without tables?

Comment: Hi Roman. yes. That's exactly what I mean. Probably I should have shown the previous code the one did which not work. I tried to use mix of float: left, right but I could not obtain the result.

Comment: want to check out, [foundaiton](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/), or [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)? it's pretty easy to setup a template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You weren't accounting for the padding.

**CSS**

```
section,article,header,footer,nav,aside,h1,h2,h3,h4,p,ul,li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html {
padding: 10px;
margin: 0;
background-color: #00d;
}
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #ddf;
}
nav {
background-color: red;
}
footer {
background-color: yellow;
clear: both;
}
li {
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: none;
}
#top {
background-color: grey;
padding: 10px 20px;
}
#container {
width: 100%;
}
#left {
vertical-align: top;
background-color: cyan;
width: 15%;
display: inline-block;
}
#main {
width: auto;
display: inline-block;
}
#right {
vertical-align: top;
background-color: magenta;
width: 25%;
display: inline-block;
position:fixed;
right:10px;
}
```

Comment: It's not working. If you add longer text in paragraphs, the right block does not scroll with the page, hides the text, and is not vertically aligned to top. I guess I stick to tables for time being. Thanks for your time anyway :)